# libruby.so.1.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql2

I am getting the below error while starting server of my project. I am trying to resolve since yesterday but was not able to solve it. somebody pls help me.

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 2.3.14 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3001
Encountered error loading /home/success/prj/myprj/vendor/gems/mysql2-0.2.18/precompiled/i686-linux/1.8.7/mysql2/mysql2.so: libruby.so.1.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/success/prj/myprj/vendor/gems/mysql2-0.2.18/precompiled/i686-linux/1.8.7/mysql2/mysql2.so
Encountered error loading /home/success/prj/myprj/vendor/gems/mysql2-0.2.18/precompiled/i686-linux/1.8.7/mysql2/mysql2.so: libruby.so.1.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/success/prj/myprj/vendor/gems/mysql2-0.2.18/precompiled/i686-linux/1.8.7/mysql2/mysql2.so
/home/success/prj/eschool/vendor/gems/mysql2-0.2.18/lib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:13: Failed to load mysql2 binary for your platform (i686-linux/1.8.7) Run ./compile_native_library.rb (RuntimeError)
        from /home/success/prj/myprj/vendor/gems/rubygems-update-1.7.2/lib/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
        from /home/success/prj/myprj/vendor/gems/rubygems-update-1.7.2/lib/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /home/success/prj/myprj/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
        from /home/success/prj/myprj/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in `new_constants_in'
        from /home/success/prj/myprj/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
        from /home/success/prj/myprj/vendor/gems/mysql2-0.2.18/lib/mysql2.rb:9
```

**UPDATE:**

```
success@success-Vostro-1400:/usr/lib$ ls -l libruby*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      19 2012-02-22 07:07 libruby1.8.so -> libruby1.8.so.1.8.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      19 2012-02-22 07:07 libruby1.8.so.1.8 -> libruby1.8.so.1.8.7
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  956360 2012-02-22 07:22 libruby1.8.so.1.8.7
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1436438 2012-02-22 07:22 libruby1.8-static.a
```

Comment: yeah the file is there.. pls tell me how can i check the permission ???

Comment: i have updated the permission details.. pls tell me if i need to change anything.

Comment: i have tried this but didnt work.. thanks man for your quick response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem following below steps :

1. uninstall all the mysql2 gems
2. install `mysql2`, version < 0.3
3. go to `vendor/gems` directory
4. execute `gem unpack mysql2`
5. execute `rake gems:refresh_specs`
6. execute `rake gems:build`
7. add config.gem `mysql2` to `environment.rb`
8. restart the server

Comment: How do you remove all mysql2 gems?

Answer (score 1):

If the library is already there and its not able to find it and saying cannot find shared object file possibly means

You need to run /sbin/ldconfig which rebuilds the shared libs cache.

[Linux questions](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/what-does-ldconfig-do-71335/)

This will surely help when you have moved some libraries to the standard path and its not cached.
Generally ldconfig will run while system is booting. Thats why few issues is going off after reboot.

Answer (score 1):

It is just can be solved by fix the versions only

first upgrade the RVM to the most stable version

```
rvm get head
```

and then reinstall your ruby version

```
rvm reinstall 1.9.3
```

Answer (score 1):

We were receiving a similar error in a circleci build, turns out that it was a circleci caching issue.
On one branch we have updated our ruby version but we haven't merged that change into the master branch, all the builds that didn't merge the ruby version upgrade failed in circleci.
The solution is changing the caching strategy.
https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/caching/

Comment: For my Rails project, this meant busting the gem cache by passing an argument to [`install-deps`](https://circleci.com/developer/orbs/orb/circleci/ruby):

`- ruby/install-deps:\n  key: 'gems-rails7'`

Answer (score 0):

quick fix :

```
cd /usr/lib
ln -s libruby1.8.so libruby.so.1.8

ldd /home/success/prj/myprj/vendor/gems/mysql2-0.2.18/precompiled/i686-linux/1.8.7/mysql2/mysql2.so
```